# PHP: Shorthand Switch

Tags: php, function, class, switch-statement

I'm looking for more comfortable/more short version of `Switch()` statement in case of using multiple functions.

I'll give you one example: imagine 100-200 functions in one class, and you want to call only one of them by setting value to `id` in that class.

In my particular case, I have the following structure of PHP file:

```
<?php

  class _main
  {
      function request($id)
      {
          switch($id)
          {
              case 0:
                  $this->writeA();
              break;
              case 1:
                  $this->writeB();
              break;

              ///...
              // then we have 100-200 functions like this in switch.
          }
      }
      function writeA()
      {
          echo('a');
      }
      function writeB()
      {
          echo('b');
      }
  }

  $id   = 1;
  $x    = new _main();
  $x->request($id);

?>
```

For some of you it may seem weird, but I don't want to have that much lines of code with `case` and `break`. For me, they are just making code more difficult to read.

(by the way, writing it 100 times will not making it fun for me too).

---

**CONCLUSION**

- What could be the best,fast and comfortable method?
- Can I store functions to array and then call them?
- And will it affect performance? Will be `Swicth()` even faster?

Thank you :)

**EDIT**

Perhaps there is a different way of thinking/coding and not only array/switch thing.

Comment: If I had 100-200 methods in my class, I would start rethinking my architecture . Are the methods very different from each other? (I'm assuming that they contain more than just `echo` IRL). What is this for? What is the class suppose to do?

Comment: haha I don't have so much experience with PHP so... :) Is it very bad to have that quantity of methods in one class?

Comment: Yes, they contain different functions.. for example I need functions that are working with database and returning different values with different convertions with var types, joining 2 or more requests, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I would ever recommend this but if you really want that many methods within a single class and a singular function to route the calls through...

```
<?php

class MyClass 
{
    public $id;

    public function callFunction()
    {
        $funcName = 'execute' . $this->id;
        return $this->$funcName();
    }

    private function execute1()
    {
        echo 'execute1() Called.';
    }

    private function execute2()
    {
        echo 'execute2() Called.';
    }
}

$c = new MyClass();
$c->id = 1;
$c->callFunction();
```

Output:

```
execute1() Called.
```

I feel like there is most likely another way to approach this with more information utilising `Interfaces` and `Abstract` classes, but with the information to go off the above might suffice your requirement.

---

**Edit:** Sadly I don't have the time right now to come up with a detailed solution, and I don't really have enough information to go off but perhaps utilising interfaces is your best solution for your requirement. Below is a *very* quick example.

```
<?php

interface WritableInterface
{
    public function write($data);
}

class VersionOneWriter implements WritableInterface
{
    public function write($data)
    {
        return $data . '<br/>';
    }
}

class VersionTwoWriter implements WritableInterface
{
    public function write($data)
    {
        return $data . $data . '<br/>';
    }
}

class MyMainClass
{
    public function request(WritableInterface $writer, $data)
    {
        return $writer->write($data);
    }
}

$c  = new MyMainClass();
$w1 = new VersionOneWriter();
$w2 = new VersionTwoWriter();

echo $c->request($w1, 'DataString');
echo $c->request($w2, 'DataString');
```

Essentially when you call your request function you pass along a `Writer` class which implements the `WritableInterface`. Anything that implements that interface has to have a `write()` method.

Now when you pass your data across with your method, since you are also passing a writer along that can handle the data you can safely call `->write($data)` within your `request()` method and the result will be dependent on the class you passed through.

If you ever need another method of writing you can just add create another `class` that implements your `interface`

Hopefully that made some sense, it was a bit of a ramble as I have to disappear for a bit. If you have any questions I'll try to check back when I have time.

--

**Edit2:**
The `define()` in this instance requires PHP7+ since I'm defining an array, but you could prior to PHP7 you could just use a standard array. `$classMap = ['FirstClass', 'SecondClass'];`

```
interface MyInterface {}
class FirstClass implements MyInterface {}
class SecondClass implements MyInterface {}

$requestParam = 1;

define('CLASS_MAP', array(
    'FirstClass',
    'SecondClass',
));

$classMap = CLASS_MAP[$requestParam]; // SecondClass

$class = new $classMap;
var_dump($class); // Dumps out: object(SecondClass)#1 (0) {}
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. It's all about architecture of my code, it can be done in very different ways. So, I'm really interested in learning some stuff about Interfaces and architecture of PHP code etc. I'm not using any framework yet.. So, how can I, for example, make request to `get.php` (just example), with `?id=...` url parameter using interfaces? By the way, using huge classes seams really expensive for web server.

Comment: One more time, Thanks for answer, @Pigeon

Comment: No worries @MaxWater Potentially you could use some form of Pivot Table to handle the mapping of which `ID` utilises which `Interface`. If you didn't want to utilise a database though potentially using a `constant` array that maps the IDs to the Interface I'll do a quick update to my initial post.

Comment: Great idea! I'll try it out, that's a good start for me! Cheers! :)